# Implementing swap/copy functions: is there a better way?

Tags: c++, data-structures

These are how I implemented the swap and copy functions for my queue.

Is there a better way?

```
template <class T>
void Queue<T>::copy(Queue<T> const & other)
{
    if(this == &other) 
        return;

    if(m_size != 0)
        this->clear();

    this->m_cap = other.m_cap;
    this->enqueue(other);
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::swap(Queue<T> const & other)
{
    if(this == &other)
        return;

    std::swap(this->m_front, other.m_front);
    std::swap(this->m_back, other.m_back);
    std::swap(this->m_size, other.m_size);
    std::swap(this->m_cap, other.m_cap);
}
```

Thank you:)

Comment: Why do you have a method named `copy` instead of just using copy constructors and copy assignment operators?

Comment: `if(this == &other)` is a sign that your copy method probably isn't exception safe.

Comment: Usually a copy is accomplished with a copy constructor. And then, assignment is accomplished with a copy and swap.

Comment: Did you really intend swap to take a reference to a constant?

Comment: First of all "better" is subjective, second we do not have enough information even to speculate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

Comment: Hey, jxh. I see the mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `copy` method, you should instead implement a copy constructor. It would be strange for the copy constructor to be passed an instance of itself. If you insist on checking, you can use an assertion.

```
template <class T>
Queue<T>::Queue(Queue<T> const & other)
    : m_cap(other.m_cap), m_size(0), m_front(), m_back()
{
    assert(&other != this);
    enqueue(other);
}
```

Your `copy` method is actually an assignment. It is more natural to implement an assignment operator. This can be accomplished by following the copy-swap idiom.

```
template <class T>
Queue<T> & Queue<T>::operator = (Queue<T> other)
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

There is also an idiomatic way to implement `swap` (taught to me by Mooing Duck a long time ago):

```
template <class T>
class Queue {
//...
    friend void swap(Queue &a, Queue &b) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(a.m_front, b.m_front);
        swap(a.m_back, b.m_back);
        swap(a.m_size, b.m_size);
        swap(a.m_cap, b.m_cap);
    }
};
```

This way, you can use argument dependent lookup (ADL) to pick the type specific `swap` implementation if available. And now `Queue` itself has such an implementation, which is used by the assignment operator. But it can also be used in the case `Queue` is put inside an object that wants to implement `swap` for itself.

Comment: Hey jxh, thanks a lot for your answer. I found it helpful and enlightening.

Comment: If I may ask one question: why would we want to to use swap when overloading =? May we not want “other” to remain as it is?

Comment: Assignment operator takes its parameter by value not by reference. Using swap allows the the contents to be destructed when the function returns.